# Before i added my password reset function my signup worked but now it gives errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I made a password reset function, but it makes my software so I can only sign up once. It gives a 400 error, but nothing more, can you maybe help me?
I get this error:

```
> MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users
> index: passwordReset.token_1 dup key: { passwordReset.token: null }
```

I share my model and my controller here:

Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { isEmail } = require("validator");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const otpGenerator = require('otp-generator');
const cron = require('node-cron');

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Je bent vergeten een email adres in te vullen"],
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: [isEmail, "Vul een geldig email adres in"]
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Je bent vergeten een wachtwoord in te vullen"],
        minlength: [5, "Zorg dat het wachtwoord minimaal 5 tekens bevat"]
    },
    points: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0,
    },
    photo: {
        type: String
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    collectedPointsInPath: [{
        path: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Path', required: true },
        point: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Point', required: true }]
    }],
    passwordReset: {
        token: {
            type: String,
            default: null,
            unique: true,
            sparse: true,
        },
        expires: Date,
    },
    userCreated: {
        type: String,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

UserSchema.post('save', function (doc, next) {
    console.log('new user was created en saved', doc);
    next();
});

UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    console.log('user about to be created', this);
    next();
});

UserSchema.methods.generatePasswordResetOTP = function () {
    const otp = otpGenerator.generate(6, { digits: true, upperCase: false, specialChars: false, alphabets: false });
    const expirationTime = new Date(Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000); // 15 minutes from now

    this.passwordReset = {
        token: otp,
        expires: expirationTime,
    };
};

UserSchema.methods.isPasswordResetOTPValid = function () {
    return this.passwordReset && this.passwordReset.expires > Date.now();  // Check if passwordReset exists before checking expiration
};

// Background task to delete expired OTPs
const deleteExpiredOTPs = async () => {
    const expiredUsers = await User.find({
        $and: [
            { 'passwordReset.token': { $ne: null } }, // Check if token exists
            { 'passwordReset.expires': { $lt: Date.now() } }
        ]
    });

    for (const user of expiredUsers) {
        user.passwordReset = {
            token: null,
            expires: null,
        };
        await user.save();
    }
};

// Schedule the deleteExpiredOTPs task to run every minute
cron.schedule('* * * * *', deleteExpiredOTPs);

UserSchema.statics.login = async function (email, password) {
    const user = await this.findOne({ email });
    if (user) {
        const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (auth) {
            return user;
        }
        throw Error('verkeerd wachtwoord');
    }
    throw Error('verkeerde email');
}

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Controller:

```
const User = require("../model/User");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const axios = require('axios');
const MailingController = require('./mailingController')
//handleerrors
const handleErrors = (err) => {
  let errors = { email: '', password: '', photo: '' };

  if (err.message === 'verkeerde email') {
    errors.email = 'Ingevoerde gegevens kloppen niet.';
  }
  if (err.message === 'verkeerde wachtwoord') {
    errors.email = 'Ingevoerde gegevens kloppen niet.';
  }
  // Check for duplicate email error
  if (err.code === 11000 && err.keyPattern && err.keyPattern.email === 1) {
    errors.email = 'Dit email adres heeft al een account bij ons';
    return errors;
  }
  // Validate errors
  if (err.message.includes('user validation failed')) {
    Object.values(err.errors).forEach(({ properties }) => {
      errors[properties.path] = properties.message;
    });
  }
  return errors;
};

const maxAge = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60;
const createToken = (id) => {
    return jwt.sign({id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET,{expiresIn:maxAge});
}


module.exports.signup_post = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, photo } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.create({ email, password, photo });
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    await MailingController.welcome_postmail(email);
    res.status(201).json({ user: user._id });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
    const errors = handleErrors(err);
    res.status(400).json(errors);
  }
};




module.exports.login_post = async(req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;
    try{
        const user = await User.login(email,password);
        const token = createToken(user._id);
        res.status(200).json({user:user._id , token: token, points:user.points});
    }
    catch(err){
        const errors = handleErrors(err);
        res.status(400).json({errors});
    }
};


module.exports.passwordReset1 = async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }
    // Check if the user already has a password reset token
    if (!user.passwordReset || !user.passwordReset.token) {
      user.generatePasswordResetOTP();
      const updatedUser = await user.save();
      MailingController.password_reset(email, updatedUser.passwordReset.token);
    }
    return res.json({ message: 'Password reset token sent' });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
};

module.exports.passwordReset2 = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, token, newPassword } = req.body;

  try {
    // Find the user by email
    const user = await User.findOne({email});
    // Check if the user exists
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }
    // Check if the OTP token is valid and not expired
    if (!user.passwordReset || !user.passwordReset.token || user.passwordReset.token !== token || !user.isPasswordResetOTPValid()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid or expired OTP token' });
    }
    user.password = newPassword;
    user.passwordReset = undefined;
    await user.save();
    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Password reset successful' });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
  }
};


module.exports.getByIdAndUpdatePoints = async (req, res) => {
  const { id, points } = req.body;
  try {
    const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id }, // Filter by user ID
      { $inc: { points: points } }, // Update points using $inc to increment/decrement
      { new: true } // Return the updated document
    );

    if (!updatedUser) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }

    return res.json(updatedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
};

  module.exports.logout_get = (req, res) => {
    res.status('jwt','',{maxAge:1});
};
  module.exports.getById = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.body;
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(id);
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
      }
      return res.json(user);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
  };
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

I added a sparse because I thought it was because my `passwordReset` is default null, and it made a duplicate error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error happens because you have set:

```
passwordReset: {
    token: {
        ...
        default: null,
        unique: true,
    },
    ...,
}
```

So when you run:

```
const user = await User.create({ email, password, photo });
```

on your `signup_post` function a value of `null` is being added by default because that's what you asked mongoose to do. However, because it's unique you won't be allowed to add another user with the same default value of `null`. If you really need it to be unique then don't set that default value to `null`. Run a `UserSchema.pre('save'...)` hook and generate a unique value because the `create()` function fires `save()` hooks. Remove that default value of `null` from your schema. You should be fine.